Telegram Bot is unable to send photo by file ID
package Bot;

import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendDocument;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendPhoto;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot
{

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "TestBobr_Bot";
    }
    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "<I hid it>";
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update)
    {
// getting FileId, ChatId, Text of the message and name of the user
        String DocumentId = update.getMessage().getDocument().getFileId();
        String ChatId = update.getMessage().getChatId().toString();
        String UserFirstName = update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName();
        String UserLastName = update.getMessage().getChat().getLastName();
        String Text = update.getMessage().getText();
// formatting unix time into usual one
        Integer UnixTime = update.getMessage().getDate();
        Date date = new Date(UnixTime*1000L);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
// sending the message back
        SendMessage SentMessage = new SendMessage();
        SendDocument SentDocument = new SendDocument();
        SentDocument.setChatId(ChatId);
        SentDocument.setCaption("This is a caption");
        SentDocument.setDocument(DocumentId);

        SentMessage.setText("User " + UserFirstName + " " + UserLastName + " Wrote: " + Text + " at " + formattedDate);
        SentMessage.setChatId(ChatId);
        try {
            this.execute(SentMessage);

        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Here's one of my classes, called "TelegramBot". It gets the user's message and the time when the user wrote it. then it formats unix tome into usual time and sends them back to user "<User's name> wrote: <user's message> at . I want my bot to get the photo, sent by the user and send it back using File ID. In Full API reference for developers, writing telegram bots wrote, that you can send files, by your document's file ID using the method SetDocument() like here:
SendDocument SentDocument = new SendDocument();
SentDocument.setChatId(ChatId);
SentDocument.setCaption("This is a caption");
SentDocument.setDocument(DocumentId);

In reference to developers wrote, that this method gets InputFile or FileId as String. But when I try to write in brackets the name of the String, which I got from the user, it shows me an error:

'setDocument(org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.@lombok.NonNull InputFile)' in 'org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendDocument' cannot be applied to '()'

So, as I understand things, this method just can't get File Id, correct? If so, how can I send files using File Id in other ways? If not, what do to fix it?

I have found an answer. To send Document using it's File_Id you should firstly create a new InputFile and pass the File_Id into it like here:
//FileId = your File_Id of the photo or document.
InputFile InputPhoto = new InputFile(FileId);

SentPhoto.setPhoto(InputPhoto);

